# How to understand the meaning of "extension" in Caratheodory extension theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

We are studying Caratheodory extension theorem at the moment, in the note, we stated that

> A measure $\mu$ on a field $\mathcal{C}$ can be extended to a measure
> on the $\sigma$-field generated by $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$ generated by
> $\mathcal{C}$, by defining $$\mu(A)\equiv\mu^*(A) \text{ for each } A\in\mathcal{A}\equiv\sigma[\mathcal{C}].$$ If $\mu$ is
> $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{C}$, then the extension is unique on
> $\mathcal{A}$ and is also $\sigma$-finite.

The $\mu^*$ is defined in the previous text where stated:

> Let $\Omega$ be arbitrary: Let $\mu$ be a measure on a field
> $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets $\Omega$. For each $A\in 2^\Omega$
> $$\mu^*=\inf\{\sum^\infty_{n=1}\mu(A_n):A\subset\cup^\infty_{n=1}A_n\text{
>  with all } A_n\in\mathcal{C}\}$$

**I am struggled to understand what really the word "extension" means.** So far we have:

1. defined the outer measure on $2^\Omega$ which is by construction a $\sigma$-field and a largest possible one. We know so long as $\mu:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ satisfies three conditions it is a well-defined measure: 1) $\mu(\emptyset)=0$; 2)$\mu(A)\geq0, \forall A\in \mathcal{A}$; 3) countably additivity $\mu(\sum^\infty A_n)=\sum^\infty\mu(A_n)$ for all disjoint $A_n\in\mathcal{A}$;
2. defined outer measure which is defined on $2^\Omega$ instead of an arbitrary field. For outer measure, we have three conditions to hold 1) $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0;2)\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)\text{ for all } A\subset B;3)$ countably subadditivity: $\mu(\cup^\infty A_n)\leq\sum^\infty \mu(A_n)$ for all $A_n\in2^\Omega$;
3. defined $\mu^*$-measurable: let $A\subset\Omega$, $A$ is measuable if $\mu(T)=\mu(TA^c)+\mu(TA)$ for all $T\subset\Omega$.

The theorem in its literal meaning means we have first defined $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}$ which is a field (yes, I understand) and we can EXTEND it to define it on $\sigma[\mathcal{C}]$. I am struggling to understand such *extend* is to what extend? I think we made several extensions in mathematical analysis as well but I never felt I understand the meaning of extension. Does that mean a certain property is preserved? Does that mean we can simply use what we have defined so far to define something new? Or does it mean something else? I checked some wiki pages as well but none helped me understand the term. I hope my question makes sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very generally speaking, if you have sets $A$ and $C$ and $f\colon A \to C$ is a map, then an *extension* of $f$ to a larger domain $B\supset A$ would be a function $\bar{f}\colon B \to C$ that coincides with $f$ on the set $A$, i.e. $$\forall x\in A\colon f(x) = \bar{f}(x).$$ In other words, the restriction of $\bar{f}$ to $A$ gives $f$.

Now in your particular case, given a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}$, which is a map $\mathcal{C}\to [0,\infty]$, it can be extended to a measure $\bar{\mu}\colon \sigma(\mathcal{C})\to [0,\infty]$, so an extension in the above sense, which means that $$\forall A\in \mathcal{C}\colon \mu(A) = \bar{\mu}(A),$$ with the additional property that this extension defines a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very clear and understandable

Comment: Glad I could help :)